# Set src to html image using JS (array of image)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, prefix

What I want to do is create a carousel of photos. So to do that, I create a array of photos that I have in a folder, next I create a function with `windows.onload` to load automatically. That function with some `if` statement should change the position of the `img`, but the problem is that i can not set src to change to every photo of the array.

```js
   window.onload = function playFoto() {
  let positionCarrusel = 0;
  let imagenEnsaladas = document.getElementById("photosEnsaladas")

  let carruselPhotos = [
    'assets/carrusel/ens.-ventresca-300-x300-300x300.png',
    'assets/carrusel/ensalada bacalao200x200.png',
    'assets/carrusel/ensalada-alcachofas-300x-300-300x300.jpg',
    'assets/carrusel/ensalada-bacalao.png'
  ];
  console.log("soy funcion playFoto")
  if (positionCarrusel < carruselPhotos.length) {
    positionCarrusel++;
  } else {
    positionCarrusel = 0;
  }

  imagenEnsaladas.src = carruselPhotos[positionCarrusel];
  playFoto()
}
```

```html
<section class="tablaNovedadesEnsalada">
  <-- that is the img -->
    <img src="" alt="photos carrusel" class="photosEnsaladas">

    <p class="textoNovedades">
      <ul>
        <li>ensalada de laminas de bacalao</li>
        <li> ensalada de laminas de bacalao</li>
        <li> Ensalada de alcachofas</li>
        <li> Ensalada de yemas</li>
        <li>ensalada de ventresca</li>
        <li>Ensalada queso cabra</li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of nodes, not a single node - even if the response is a single node, the response is still a list/collection/array

Comment: Where is the element with id `photoCarrusel`?

Comment: i forgot to erase I was trying too many thinks

Comment: Simply running your code gives : `Uncaught ReferenceError: imagenEnsaladas is not defined`.

Comment: that it say the console

Comment: main.js:39 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of undefined
    at changeSrc (main.js:39)
    at playFoto (main.js:50)

Comment: but if hay do consolo.log(imagenEnsaladas)

Comment: that say HTMLCollection [img#photosEnsaladas.photosEnsaladas, photosEnsaladas: img#photosEnsaladas.photosEnsaladas]